# How to pass data between components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to display the form data submitted but the map is throwing an error.

I have two components

```
NameForm.js
```

Here is the form input, `handlechange` and `handlesubmit` methods are done

```js
function Nameform() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({firstname: "", lastname: ""});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [e.target.id]: (e.target.value),
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello from handle submit", form );
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div className='card pa-30'>
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
          <div className='layout-column mb-15'>
            <label htmlFor='name' className='mb-3'>First Name</label>
            <input 
              type='text' 
              id='firstname'
              placeholder='Enter Your First Name'
              data-testid='nameInput'
              value={form.firstname}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
                    <div className='layout-column mb-15'>
            <label htmlFor='name' className='mb-3'>First Name</label>
            <input 
              type='text' 
              id='firstname'
              placeholder='Enter Your First Name'
              data-testid='nameInput'
              value={form.firstname}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
       
          <div className='layout-row justify-content-end'>
            <button 
              type='submit'
              className='mx-0'
              data-testid='addButton'
            >
              Add Name
            </button>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div> 
    </section>
  )
}

export default Nameform
```

```
NameList.js
```

I want to pass the data in handleSubmit in NameForm.js to NameList.js. But the data is not displayed.

```js
function NameList({form}) {
    return (
      <section>
      {form.map(displayName => {
        return (
           <ul 
        className='styled w-100 pl-0' 
      >
      <li 
        className='flex slide-up-fade-in justify-content-between'
      >
        <div className='layout-column w-40'>
          <h3 className='my-3'>{displayName.firstname}</h3>
          <p className='my-0'{displayName.lastname}></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      </ul>
        )
      })}
     </section>
  )
}

export default NameList;
```

```
App.js
```

In App.js, I want to display both the form and the data.

```js
import { Nameform, Namelist } from './components'

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='layout-row justify-content-center mt-100'>
        <div className='w-30 mr-75'>
          <Nameform />
        </div>
        <div className='layout-column w-30'>
          <NameList /> 
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the data you want to share between parent and children via props (which stands for properties).

In the parent class, when rendering `<NameForm>` and `<ListForm>` add the data like that:

```
//if you want to share count and name for example: 
<NameForm 
count={this.state.count}
name={this.state.name}
 />
```

You can add as many props as you want. Furthermore, you can pass a function and its argument using arrow functions:

```
<NameForm 
aFunction={() => this.myFunction( /*  anArgument  */ )} 
/>
```

To access props in a child class dynamically wherever you need them:

```
{this.props.count}
{this.props.name}
{this.props.aFucntion}
```

You can get rid of this.props using a technique called object destructing:

```
render(

   const {count, name, aFunction} = this.props;

   //now you can use {count} and {name} and {aFunction} without this.props 
);
```

Comment: Hello @T farah, the two components are not like parent and child. Both are rendered in App.js. IF child and Parent, I could have rendered the NameList.js in NameForm.js

Comment: Hey @EmmanuelOga, whatever classes you want to share data between, you have to use props. If the two components are rendered in the same class, then the data itself must be intialized or/and declared in the state, or in render(), thus, you can access it using {this.state.data} or {data} if data is declared in render(). If the data is in another class than App.js, you may consider lifting the state up to App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state in the **parent component** and **pass it** as props to the **child components** like so.

Here we make use of an outer state called `submittedForm` to display only the submitted values. The inner `form` state is being used for handling the values before submitting.

```
// App.js

function App() {
  const [submittedForm, setSubmittedForm] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="layout-row justify-content-center mt-100">
        <div className="w-30 mr-75">
          <NameForm setSubmittedForm={setSubmittedForm} />
        </div>
        <div className="layout-column w-30">
          <NameList form={submittedForm} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// NameForm.js

function NameForm({ setSubmittedForm }) {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // setActive(true);
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmittedForm(form);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="card pa-30">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="layout-column mb-15">
            <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-3">
              First Name
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstname"
              placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
              data-testid="nameInput"
              value={form.firstname}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="layout-column mb-15">
            <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-3">
              Last Name
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastname"
              placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"
              data-testid="nameInput"
              value={form.lastname}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="layout-row justify-content-end">
            <button type="submit" className="mx-0" data-testid="addButton">
              Add Name
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default NameForm;
```

```
// NameList.js

function NameList({ form }) {
  return (
    <section>
      <ul className="styled w-100 pl-0">
        <li className="flex slide-up-fade-in justify-content-between">
          <div className="layout-column w-40">
            <h3 className="my-3">{form.firstname}</h3>
            <p className="my-0">{form.lastname}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}

export default NameList;
```

Comment: Hello @sm3sher, I tried to follow your instruction but, get an error. Please, how will the NameList.js looks like? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @EmmanuelOga, I've added an example for `NameList` component. I was assuming the form object stays the same with `firstname` and `lastname` keys.

Comment: Hello @sm3sher, I appreciate your help. My question is after adding the first data if I want to add another data, the initial data is overwritten. 

Also, I do not want the data to display until I click submit. How to prevent it.

For example, I want to add John Doe. As I am typing john, it will display the letters as I type. 

 Thank you.

Comment: @EmmanuelOga I edited my answer accordingly. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you mind if I share my email with you and schedule a zoom meeting? It is a practice that is giving headaches. Making it work will boost my experience. Thank you.

Comment: I am working as a freelancer, I could do that in an hourly basis of 40€

Comment: Thank you @sm3sher. I would love to pay and add experience to my skill, but I cannot afford it. I am a beginner. It is a personal practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your code, first `form` is an `object` not an `array`, so you can't `map` it, you need to use `form.firstname` and `form.lastname`, Also you set both `input` ids equal `firstname` you need to modify it, Also you need to move the `form` state and `handleChange` function to the `App` component.

This is a working code of your example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-forest-328bon

Comment: Hello @mina, each time I type the previous item is overwritten. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Please, open the codesandbox, I provided it should work perfectly.

Comment: Hello @mina, I understand. My question is after adding the first data if I want to add another data, the initial data is overwritten. 

How can I prevent that? Thank you.